# Matplotlib: cannot use Tex anymore (Mac OS Sonoma)

Tags: python, matplotlib, macos-sonoma

I recently got a new laptop with Mac OS Sonoma 14.2.1, to which I migrated the data from my Big Sur laptop via TimeMachine. I updated Xcode and then followed the MacPorts instructions for migration (https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration). I also updated gcc to gcc 13.2 (https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases), fortran code compiles fine.

The issue: matplotlib does not plot when using Tex. I get the following output:

```
    In [1]: p.plot([0,1],[0,1])
    Installed osx event loop hook.
    Out[1]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x16a8c70d0>]

    In [2]: PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (zlib library version does not match - header: 1.3, library: 1.3.1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1226, in _on_timer
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 68, in callback_func
        callback()
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 88, in _draw_idle
        self.draw()
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 50, in draw
        super().draw()
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 400, in draw
        self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
        result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
        return draw(artist, renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3175, in draw
        mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
        a.draw(renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
        return draw(artist, renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 3064, in draw
        mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
        a.draw(renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
        return draw(artist, renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1389, in draw
        tlb1, tlb2 = self._get_ticklabel_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1316, in _get_ticklabel_bboxes
        return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1316, in <listcomp>
        return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 959, in get_window_extent
        bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 378, in _get_layout
        _, lp_h, lp_d = _get_text_metrics_with_cache(
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 97, in _get_text_metrics_with_cache
        return _get_text_metrics_with_cache_impl(
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 105, in _get_text_metrics_with_cache_impl
        return renderer_ref().get_text_width_height_descent(text, fontprop, ismath)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 226, in get_text_width_height_descent
        return super().get_text_width_height_descent(s, prop, ismath)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 645, in get_text_width_height_descent
        return self.get_texmanager().get_text_width_height_descent(
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 371, in get_text_width_height_descent
        page, = dvi
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 296, in __iter__
        while self._read():
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 375, in _read
        self._dtable[byte](self, byte)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 227, in wrapper
        return method(self, *[f(self, byte-min) for f in get_args])
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 526, in _fnt_def
        self._fnt_def_real(k, c, s, d, a, l)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 531, in _fnt_def_real
        tfm = _tfmfile(fontname)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 1132, in _fontfile
        return cls(_find_tex_file(texname + suffix))
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 1110, in _find_tex_file
        raise FileNotFoundError(
        FileNotFoundError: Matplotlib's TeX implementation searched for a file named 'cmss10.tfm' in your texmf tree, but could not find it
```

The texmf tree is present in `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm`. Running `kpsewhich cmss10.tfm` in the terminal gives the correct path. However, matplotlib.dviread can't find it.

I have explicitly put `export TEXMFHOME=/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm` and `export TEXMFLOCAL=/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm` in the bash_profile, this does not solve the issue. Plotting worked fine before updating Xcode and migrating macports...

Does anyone have any ideas to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- use the following to go to In your Matplotlib configuration file:
  (matplotlibrc) and Make sure `text.usetex` is `False` --Search using `CTRL+F` #text.usetex.

use below code in terminal to get there

```
 `python -c "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())"`
```

- Rebuild Matplotlib Font Cache

  python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.figure(); plt.close()"
- Reinstall MacPorts Packages:

  `sudo port uninstall texlive +full`

  `sudo port install texlive +full`

Comment: The issue apparently lies with luatex: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/69184#ticket.
Here's hoping the patch is implemented soon...

Comment: @marie It is good to know that.

Comment: And it's now fixed! The macports developers were very helpful and fast, the texlive-bin patch has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's now fixed! The luatex issue was patched in texlive-bin. (The macports developers were very helpful and fast!)